# Interacting with HID devices using LibUsbDotNet in C#

Tags: c#, usb, libusb

Simply put: **I would like to know if its possible, with LibUsbDotNet, to read and write HID feature reports.**

In the first place I tried to find my device using vid/pid with following example code

```
class Program
    {
        public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;
        public static UsbDeviceFinder uFind = new UsbDeviceFinder(1234,4321);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

            try
            {
                // Find and open the usb device.
                MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(uFind);

                // If the device is open and ready
                if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");
```

But I would always get **Device Not Found.**

I have checked under "Device manager > Human Interface Devices" my device does exists.

It would be helpful if someone can suggest what is the *right method* to achieve the same in c#.

Previously I tried to achieve the same in python( using PyUsb ) but lack of examples and documentation made me hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the installation folder of libUsbDotNet there is a file named "inf-wizard.exe" run that app and install a "fake driver" used by libUsbDotNet to find the driver.

> if you can't find "inf-wizard.exe" try downloading libUsbDotNet from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/

You may have to use the device manager to find the Pid and Vid for the specific driver(even if no driver is found it the Vid and Pid should be displayed)

After installing convert the Pid and Vid to integers, this site may be helpfull http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

use the converted integers in the code ex:

```
//Hex Values: Pid = 4D9; Vid = 1605; 

public static UsbDeviceFinder uFind = new UsbDeviceFinder(1241, 5637);
```

Windows requires a driver to commuticate with any type of hardware, this process is a lot simpler in linux, see [link (connect hack)](http://learn.adafruit.com/hacking-the-kinect/overview) for a good simplification on how usb communication works. (This is linux based, but the core stays the same)

Comment: Hi there. The  'inf-wizard' _doesn't lists_ **HID-Device** .It works for anything else but not for **HID**. **Are you sure** that 'inf-wizard' can create a fake driver for **HID** devices.

Comment: Yes, as I have done it before, yet you might want to change the settings as the default settings in LibUsbDotNet is to only send/receive 64 bits at a time, I had trouble when trying to communicate with a keyboard as it opperated on 8 bit intervals, If I pressed 8 keys in close succession it would read. There is a buffer setting that should solve this problem, but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: Try using the included examples in the LibUsbDotNet library.